# Inter paragraph space in libreoffice-writer

Tags: libreoffice

I have a pretty ordinary document where I see different spacing between different paragraphs (the some paragraphs are separated by extra space, some are not).
I cannot figure out where this is set.
I tried the following:

1. select the neighboring paragraphs and right click mouse, select "line spacing" - it is always `single`, whether there is extra inter-paragraph space or not.
2. `format` -> `paragraph` -> `indent & spacing`: spacing both below and above paragraphs is empty, line spacing is single.

My question is: how do I make all my paragraphs the same style (i.e., I want uniform inter-paragraph space in the whole document).

Comment: maybe this helps: select your text, choose F11 and choose 'standard' for the paragraph style

Answer (score 0):

That can be affected by both the style and and "direct formatting."  For example, you can apply a set style to all of your paragraphs, and then decide that one or two paragraphs need more or less spacing. To do that, you select the paragraph (or part of it) and the Format>Paragraph (or get to the same point using the right-click menu.)

This brings up the paragraph formatting menu, where you can change the before and after spacing. If you do this, your selected paragraph will have different spacing to the others, even though it has the same style applied.

TO fix this, select all the affected paragraphs (at once, or a few at a time) then Format>"Clear direct formatting." That will leave only the style.

Note that the line spacing is also specified in the style, and can also be overridden on a per-paragraph basis.